# Fetch posts from different tables order by time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I have 4 mysql tables namely `post_type1`,`post_type2`,`post_type3`,`post_type4` . These 4 tables have different no. of columns and different structure . Common columns in them are `'id'` which is primary key and time (datetime) which is the time at which post was written. 
If i were to fetch last 10 posts from a table i could do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM post_type1 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10
```

But what if i want to get last 10 posts no matter which of the 4 table they belong.

1 idea came into my head which is very inefficient that is to fetch 10 records from each of the table (total of 40 records) then using php to apply a merge sort and get the top 10 records. 
Is there any efficient way to do this? I'm really stuck into this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by common column is ID ? is ID is a foreign key between the four of the tables ?

Comment: No, I mean that id is a column which is present in all of the tables despite of their different structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `UNION` to combine them. Since they have different columns, you'll need to add placeholders in the subqueries for the missing columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT "post_type1" AS tablename, id, time, col1, col2, NULL AS col3, col4, col5
    FROM post_type1
    ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10
    UNION
    SELECT "post_type2" AS tablename, id, time, col1, NULL, col3, col4, NULL
    FROM post_type2
    ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10
    UNION
    SELECT "post_type3" AS tablename, id, time, NULL, col2, col3, col4, col5
    FROM post_type3
    ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10
    UNION
    SELECT "post_type4" AS tablename, id, time, col1, col2, col3, NULL, NULL
    FROM post_type4
    ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10    
)
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Make sure all the tables have an index on the `time` column:

```
ALTER TABLE post_type1 ADD INDEX (time)
```

Comment: Seems like a very nice solution. But i want to know about speed of this query. Can i count on this in terms of efficiency?

Comment: Make sure you have an index on `time` in all the tables. Then it will be very efficient. Each of the subqueries will use their index to get the newest 10 rows in each. Then merging and sorting 40 rows should be trivial.

Comment: How can i add index on time? Please tell me. I didn't get that completely.

Comment: I added an example to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Why select 10 users? I don't think merging is a good idea too. I think it is good to use UNION as @Barmar  wrote and put the result to an array. Then you can do what ever you want with the array.